# PHP scripting to get.post_process dreamfactory

Tags: php, mysql, dreamfactory

I have a MySQL database that is connected to dreamfactory, but some of my records are serialized (PHP). I wrote a PHP script to unserialize it whenever I send a "GET" network request, but it's not working. I am obtaining my database information from a Swift xcode project using AFNetworking and would like to display the unserialized information.

Can anyone see which part am I doing wrong?
Here's where I put my php script and the script itself:

mysql.table.[tablename}.{id}.get.post_process

```
$data = $response.meta_value;  

function toJSON($theDATA) {  
$uns = unserialize(unserialize($theDATA));  
$DATA = json_encode($uns);  
return $DATA;  
}  

$new_data = toJSON($data);  
return $new_data;
```

this is the php serialize:

```
{
"meta_value" = "s:306:\"a:1:{i:274;a:1:{s:9:\"schedules\";a:1:{s:13:\"56f5dc96a042f\";a:5:{s:13:\"minutes_start\";s:3:\"540\";s:11:\"minutes_end\";s:4:\"1020\";s:5:\"weeks\";a:7:{i:1;s:2:\"on\";i:2;s:2:\"on\";i:3;s:2:\"on\";i:4;s:2:\"on\";i:5;s:2:\"on\";i:6;s:2:\"on\";i:0;s:2:\"on\";}s:10:\"date_start\";s:10:\"03/25/2016\";s:8:\"date_end\";s:10:\"06/15/2016\";}}}}\";";
}
```

and this is what I am trying to get which is json body:

```
{"274":{"schedules":{"56f5dc96a042f":{"minutes_start":"540","minutes_end":"1020","weeks":{"1":"on","2":"on","3":"on","4":"on","5":"on","6":"on","0":"on"},"date_start":"03\/25\/2016","date_end":"06\/15\/2016"}}}}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `unserialize` twice? Plus you're not checking your return value on `json_encode`. It may be failing because of formatting or something.

Comment: the reason that I'm calling unserialize twice is because the meta value has been serialize twice. how do I check my return value on json_encode?

Comment: Have you enabled [debugging](https://guide.dreamfactory.com/docs/chapter02.html#enabling-debugging-and-logging) to take a deeper look at what the script is actually doing? That would be the best start to debugging the script.